# Problems with nested gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to design gridview inside gridview with insert update and delete but in this i cant insert record. Can anyone Help?

Here is database table

```
1) tbl_SShow(ShowTimeId{P-Auto inc.},TheatreId,MovieId,FromDate,ToDate)
2) tbl_Show(ShowID{P-Auto inc.},ShowTime,Silver,Gold, Platinum,ShowTimeId) 
3) tbl_Theatre(TheatreId{P-Auto inc.}, TName, Taddress)
```

and here is aspx page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
        function expandcollapse(obj,row)
        {
            var div = document.getElementById(obj);
            var img = document.getElementById('img' + obj);

            if (div.style.display == "none")
            {
                div.style.display = "block";
                if (row == 'alt')
                {
                    img.src = "minus.gif";
                }
                else
                {
                    img.src = "minus.gif";
                }
                img.alt = "Close to view other Customers";
            }
            else
            {
                div.style.display = "none";
                if (row == 'alt')
                {
                    img.src = "plus.gif";
                }
                else
                {
                    img.src = "plus.gif";
                }
                img.alt = "Expand to show Orders";
            }
        } 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

            <form id="AddEventForm" runat="server">
                           <ul id="tabsmenu1" class="tabsmenu">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#tab2">Add Show Time</a></li>
                            </ul>

                                <div class="form">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#f1f1f1" 
                                        AutoGenerateColumns=false DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="MovieID" 
                                        GridLines=None OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
                                        OnRowCommand = "GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating = "GridView1_RowUpdating" BorderStyle=Outset
                                        OnRowDeleting = "GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowDeleted = "GridView1_RowDeleted"
                                        OnRowUpdated = "GridView1_RowUpdated" AllowSorting=true
                                        Width="80%" >
                                        <RowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0083C1" ForeColor="White"/>
                                        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" />
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <a href="javascript:expandcollapse('div<%# Eval("ShowTimeId") %>', 'one');">
                                                        <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("ShowTimeId") %>" alt="Click to show/hide Orders for Customer <%# Eval("ShowTimeId") %>"  width="9px" border="0" src="../images/plus.gif"/>
                                                    </a>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Theatre Id" SortExpression="TheatreId">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblShowTimeId" Text='<%# Eval("ShowTimeId") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblShowTimeId" Text='<%# Eval("ShowTimeId") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Theatre Id" SortExpression="TheatreId">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTheatreId" Text='<%# Eval("TheatreId") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTheatreId" Text='<%# Eval("TheatreId") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTheatre" runat="server" CssClass="form_input" AutoPostBack="True" TabIndex="1">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Movie Id" SortExpression="MovieId">
                                                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("MovieId")%></ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMovie" runat="server" CssClass="form_input" AutoPostBack="True" TabIndex="2">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMovie" runat="server" CssClass="form_input" AutoPostBack="True" TabIndex="2">
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="From Date" SortExpression="FromDate">
                                                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("FromDate")%></ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" Text='<%# Eval("FromDate") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/cal/calendar.gif" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" TabIndex="3" />
                                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFromDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="ImageButton1">
                                                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/cal/calendar.gif" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" TabIndex="3" />
                                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFromDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="ImageButton1">
                                                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To Date" SortExpression="ToDate">
                                                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("ToDate")%></ItemTemplate>
                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" Text='<%# Eval("ToDate") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/cal/calendar.gif" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" TabIndex="3" />
                                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtToDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="ImageButton2">
                                                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/cal/calendar.gif" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" TabIndex="3" />
                                                    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtToDate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="ImageButton2">
                                                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" />
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDeleteShow" CommandName="Delete" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkAddShow" CommandName="AddShow" runat="server">Add</asp:LinkButton>
                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>

                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="100%">
                                                            <div id="div<%# Eval("ShowTimeId") %>" style="display:none;position:relative;left:15px;OVERFLOW: auto;WIDTH:97%" >

                                                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true" BackColor="White" Width=100% Font-Size=X-Small
                                                                AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Verdana" DataKeyNames="ShowTimeId" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" 
                                                                OnPageIndexChanging="GridView2_PageIndexChanging" OnRowUpdating = "GridView2_RowUpdating" CssClass="Gridview" 
                                                                OnRowCommand = "GridView2_RowCommand" OnRowEditing = "GridView2_RowEditing" GridLines=None
                                                                OnRowUpdated = "GridView2_RowUpdated" OnRowCancelingEdit = "GridView2_CancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound = "GridView2_RowDataBound"
                                                                OnRowDeleting = "GridView2_RowDeleting" OnRowDeleted = "GridView2_RowDeleted" OnSorting = "GridView2_Sorting"
                                                                BorderStyle=Double BorderColor="#0083C1">
                                                            <RowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
                                                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#0083C1" ForeColor="White"/>
                                                            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" />
                                                            <Columns>
                                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Show ID" SortExpression="ShowID">
                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblShowID" Text='<%# Eval("ShowID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblShowID" Text='<%# Eval("ShowID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ShowTime" SortExpression="ShowTime">
                                                                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("ShowTime")%></ItemTemplate>
                                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtShowTime" Text='<%# Eval("ShowTime")%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtShowTime" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Silver" SortExpression="Silver">
                                                                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Silver")%></ItemTemplate>
                                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSilver" Text='<%# Eval("Silver")%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSilver" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gold" SortExpression="Gold">
                                                                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Gold")%></ItemTemplate>
                                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGold" Text='<%# Eval("Gold")%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGold" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Platinum" SortExpression="Platinum">
                                                                <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Platinum")%></ItemTemplate>
                                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPlatinum" Text='<%# Eval("Platinum")%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                                <FooterTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPlatinum" Text='' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                </FooterTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" />
                                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDeleteCust" CommandName="Delete" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                                                 </ItemTemplate>
                                                                 <FooterTemplate>
                                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkAddOrder" CommandName="AddShow" runat="server">Add</asp:LinkButton>
                                                                 </FooterTemplate>
                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            </Columns>
                                                            </asp:GridView>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>

                                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Event_MovieConnectionString %>" 
                                        SelectCommand="SELECT s.[ShowTimeId], s.[TheatreId], s.[MovieId], s.[FromDate], s.[ToDate], s.[Created], 
                                        s.[Modified] FROM [tbl_SShow] s ORDER BY s.[ShowTimeId]">
                                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                               </div>
            </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Please give me a solutions

Thanks.

Comment: Please describe the *exact* problem

Comment: when i click on insert button then record cant insert into database. i give my cs file in answer. thanks.

Comment: That doesn't describle anything, include only relevant code, and state what does happen.. (and what you have tried if it helps!)

Comment: Which GridView, the outer or the inner one? What goes wrong if you try? Do `update` and `delete` work normally?

Comment: Both inner and outer. when i click add then record cant insert record. In inner grid view update and delete work perfect and in outer gridview problem with bind record in ddlMovie dynemically movie are come from database.

Comment: hi Mr Lister, i have a problem in both GridView inner and outer. please give me the solutions.

Comment: Hello Mr. Lister do have solution for this? If you have then please give me, Thanks